# Crash reported in crashlytics. Partial apply in closure #1

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift3

I am getting a crash reported in crashlytics about partial apply in closure. I have tried other answers that mainly focus on using [weak self] but that didn't help. However, i am not getting a crash on my device.
According to the report the crash is somewhere in the function where i show my dropDown here is the code

```
func showDropDown(_ names: [String], forResult result: SearchPatientResultResponnse) {
        guard let vc = viewController
        else { return }
        self.searchedPatientNames = result.data?.patientSearchSuggestions
        Helpers.showSearchDropdown(anchorView: vc.searchBar.searchTextField, dataSource: names, scrollToTop: true, completion: { [weak self] (i, item) in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            vc.searchBar.text = item
            vc.dismissKeyboard()
            self.selectedSearchPatient = self.searchedPatientNames?[i]
            if let d = self.searchedPatientNames?[i].dob {
                vc.dobTF.text = DateTimeFormatters.userUIDateFormatterInUTC.string(from: d)
            }
            self.search(self.selectedSearchFilter)
        }, fetchPaginationData: { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self, !self.isNameSearchLastPage, self.page != -1 else {
                return
            }
            vc.searchBar.isLoadingWithoutSearchIcon = true
            self.fetchPatientNameNextPage()
        }, cancel: { [weak self] in
            self?.resetPaginationParams()
        })
    }
```

This is the function from where i am calling this showDropDown function

```
    func getQueryPatientResponse() {
        guard let vc = viewController else {
            return
        }
        SocketIOManager.shared.queryResponseForPatient = { [weak self] result in
            var names: [String] = []
            self?.isNameSearchLastPage = result.data?.isLastPage ?? true
            self?.page = result.data?.pageNumber ?? -1
            for data in result.data?.patientSearchSuggestions ?? [] {
                var name = ""
                if !data.middleName.isEmpty {
                    name = data.firstName + " " + data.middleName + " " + data.lastName
                } else {
                    name = data.firstName + " " + (data.lastName)
                }
                names.append(name)
            }
            vc.searchBar.isLoadingWithoutSearchIcon = false
            self?.page == 1 ? self?.showDropDown(names, forResult: result) : self?.updateDropDown(names, forResult: result)
        }
    }
```

This is the crash report from crashlytics:-

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Ovada CM - PT                  0x639b0 closure #1 in VisitStatusViewModel.showDropDown(_:forResult:)
 + 4340890032 (<compiler-generated>:4340890032)
1  Ovada CM - PT                  0x3f328 partial apply for closure #1 in static Helpers.showSearchDropdown(anchorView:dataSource:scrollToTop:completion:fetchPaginationData:cancel:)
 + 121 (Helpers.swift:121)
2  Ovada CM - PT                  0x15604c DropDown.tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)
 + 4341882956 (<compiler-generated>:4341882956)
3  Ovada CM - PT                  0x156548 @objc DropDown.tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)
 + 4341884232 (<compiler-generated>:4341884232)
4  UIKitCore                      0xfe36d0 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:isCellMultiSelect:deselectPrevious:]
 + 1640
5  UIKitCore                      0xfe3050 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:]
 + 112
6  UIKitCore                      0xfe394c -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:]
 + 316
7  UIKitCore                      0x30c240 -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 64
8  UIKitCore                      0x227770 -[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush] + 200
9  UIKitCore                      0x155eb0 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 640
10 UIKitCore                      0x15657c _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 128
11 UIKitCore                      0x156748 _afterCACommitHandler + 56
12 CoreFoundation                 0x3e83c _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION_ + 32
13 CoreFoundation                 0xfa74 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 616
14 CoreFoundation                 0xaffc __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1e250 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
16 GraphicsServices               0x1988 GSEventRunModal + 160
17 UIKitCore                      0x4e5a94 -[UIApplication _run] + 1080
18 UIKitCore                      0x27efd4 UIApplicationMain + 336
19 Ovada CM - PT                  0x6070 main + 14 (AppDelegate.swift:14)
20 ???                            0x1029dc4d0 (Missing)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome ! Could you please provide the stack trace from the crashlytics ?

Comment: @Pierre yeah sure

Comment: Sorry, I wrote stack trace, but I meant the entire report. What is the error indicated in the report ? Or at least a signal (SIGABRT, SIGILL,...) ?